# How to run vite server if index.html file is not in the root directory

Tags: node.js, npm, web-deployment, tailwind-css, vite

[image]

- Index.html & app.css is outside of the /tailwindcss/...
- Vite Server is running but not working on localhost.

How to fix this problem

I don't want to put index.html in directory tailwindcss.

Comment: Logged a bug for this: https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/13249

Answer (score 5):

Vite looks for a root `index.html` by default. You can change this behaviour  in `package.json`.

To do this, simply modify the following to suit...

```
"scripts": {
  "dev": "vite serve ./src"
},
```

In this example, I've put my entry `index.html` file inside a `src` folder. I tell Vite about this via `serve`, following that with the relevant directory (file path is relative to project root).

Read more [here](https://vitejs.dev/guide/#index-html-and-project-root).

Comment: This doesn't work for me. If I change the scripts and move my index.html file one folder down all Vue components compilation breaks. I've logged a bug - https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/13249

Comment: Key quote from Answer's link: > You can specify an alternative root with `vite serve some/sub/dir`. \
Though, The Vite Cli page talks nothing about `serve`.

Comment: seems that: you can change the folder location, but the name must be `index.html`...

Answer (score 4):

You could try specifying the entry point used by Rollup explicitly:

```
// vite.config.ts
export default {
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      input: {
        // entry point for compilation; normally would be "./index.html"
        app: '../index.html',
```

but honestly it feels like you're fighting against the tools, and you should have that `package.json` one directory up in your project.

Comment: What I'm attempting to do is isolate many micro apps in a mono repo via 1 vite config and 1 vite dev command.  So i.e. /customer /admin are separate index html files that load assets off our cdn in prod on two separate apps (we just copy the index.html to the right app in prod).  The prod build works fine, but in local dev it will not load a missing index.html in the root.  We need the root to be there, because I want to use a reverse proxy to proxy / to the backend local mvc app, but have /admin and /etc be in the local dev server in vite.  Think I'll just use exp and middleware it.

Comment: It's a unified code base, /admin uses many of the same components that the other apps use in the mono repo etc, it would be a royal pita to separate them, and making separate packages doesn't make sense either.   It's literally just 4 isolated areas of the same app.

Answer (score 0):

Vite has a direct configuration option for this which can be specified in vite.config.js.

https://vitejs.dev/config/shared-options.html#root

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import path from "path";

export default defineConfig({
  root: path.resolve('./src'),
  build: {
    // Relative to the root
    outDir: '../dist',
  },
});
```